# Generating a waveform with three pulses using FSM?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

Hi All I want to generate two waveform or signal(let say mode-1 and mode-2 signal) through FSM each having three pulses let's say P1, P2,and P3. these pulse are of width 0.8us each.
for mode-1 P1 and p2 are 2 us apart and  p1 and p3 are 8 us apart (from start of the pulse)
for Mode-2 P1 and P2 are same as above while P3 is of 21 us apart.

and after 1 ms these pulses repeats it self.
I have been using 50 Mhz as my input clock freq.

this following peace of code i have written using FSM

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Signal_pulse is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           modes : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           P_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end signal_pulse;

architecture Behavioral of signal_pulse is
type state_type is (P0, P1, P2, P3);
signal Next_state, Present_state : state_type;
signal count : integer range 0 to 100000000;
signal temp : integer range 0 to 100000000;
begin 
    Process(rst, clk)
        begin
         if(rst = '1') then
               Present_state <= P0;

         elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then 
                temp <= temp +1;
               Present_state <= Next_state;
                if (temp = 50000) then
                   temp <= 1;
                end if;
                --count <= count+1;
            end if;
    end process;

    state_Process: Process(Present_state)
        begin
                case present_state is
                    when P0 =>
                           if (rst ='1') then
                                P_out <= '0';
                                count <= 0;
                                next_state <= P0;
                           else
                                 count <= 0;
                                next_state <= P1;
                           end if;
                    when P1 =>
                        if(modes = "001") then
                                if (count<40) then
                                    P_out <= '1';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count < 100) then
                                     P_out <= '0';
                                     count <= count+1;
                                     next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count = 100) then
                                     next_state <= p2;
                                end if;
                         elsif (modes = "010") then
                                if (count<40) then
                                    P_out <= '1';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count < 100) then
                                    P_out <= '0';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count = 100) then
                                    next_state <= p2;
                                end if;
                          else
                              P_out <= '0';
                          end if;
                    when P2 =>
                       if(modes = "001") then
                                 if (count < 140) then
                                        P_out <= '1';
                                        count <= count+1;
                                        next_state <= p2;
                                  elsif(count < 400) then
                                        P_out <= '0';
                                        count <= count+1;
                                        next_state <= p2;
                                  elsif(count = 400) then
                                       next_state <= P3;
                                  end if;
                        elsif (modes = "010") then    
                                if (count < 140) then
                                    P_out <= '1';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p2;
                                 elsif(count < 1050) then
                                    P_out <= '0';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p2;
                                elsif(count = 1050) then
                                    next_state <= P3;
                                end if;
                        else
                             P_out <= '0';
                        end if;
                    when P3 =>
                        if(modes = "001") then
                                 if (count < 440) then 
                                      count <= count +1;
                                      P_out <= '1';
                                      next_state <= p3;
                                 elsif (temp = 50000) then
                                      count <= 0;
                                      --temp <= 1;
                                      next_state <= P1;
                                 else
                                      P_out <= '0';
                                      next_state <= P3;
                                 end if;
                         elsif(Modes = "010") then
                                if (count < 1090) then 
                                      count <= count +1;
                                      P_out <= '1';
                                      next_state <= P3;
                                 elsif (temp = 50000) then
                                      count <= 0;
                                      --temp <= 1;
                                      next_state <= P1;
                                 else
                                      P_out <= '0';
                                      next_state <= P3;
                                 end if;
                         else
                             P_out <= '0';
                         end if;
             end case;
    end Process;                
end Behavioral;
```

but my output is constantly set at high. please suggest what i'm doing wrong.
any help would be highly appreciated 
and pardon me if there are silly mistakes I am beginner just 2 weeks into vhdl
thanks

---

[image: Mode 2 repetition]

[image: Mode 2 @start]

[image: Mode 1 at @start]

[image: Mode-1 After 1 ms repetition]

I have made some changes in code also As shown in the Images for mode 1 I'm getting correct signal at start and also after 1 ms repetition.
but for mode-2 when mode-2 starts i'm not getting correct pulse but after 1 ms repetition i'm getting correct pulses of mode-2 signal.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few modifications in your HDL changed two process FSM as Single process, The states and outputs is actually changing now,
 Though the Books and Literature use Two Process, It's now recommended by many professionals and unofficial standard to use single process, Although there were big discussions and arguments for determining which is better, I feel there isn't much difference, Although you have to take care of sensitivity list of the combinational process incase you are using two or three process, Incomplete process can cause problems in combinational process like you were facing, For Beginner I recommend Single Process unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Signal_pulse is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           modes : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           P_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end signal_pulse;

architecture Behavioral of signal_pulse is
type state_type is (P0, P1, P2, P3);
signal Next_state, Present_state : state_type;
signal count : integer range 0 to 100000000;
signal temp : integer range 0 to 100000000;
begin 
    Process(rst, clk)
        begin
         if(rst = '1') then
               Present_state <= P0;

         elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then 
                temp <= temp +1;
               Present_state <= Next_state;
                if (temp = 50000) then
                   temp <= 1;
                end if;
                --count <= count+1;

                case present_state is
                    when P0 =>
                           if (rst ='1') then
                                P_out <= '0';
                                count <= 0;
                                next_state <= P0;
                           else
                                 count <= 0;
                                next_state <= P1;
                           end if;
                    when P1 =>
                        if(modes = "001") then
                                if (count<40) then
                                    P_out <= '1';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count < 100) then
                                     P_out <= '0';
                                     count <= count+1;
                                     next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count = 100) then
                                     next_state <= p2;
                                end if;
                         elsif (modes = "010") then
                                if (count<40) then
                                    P_out <= '1';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count < 100) then
                                    P_out <= '0';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p1;
                                elsif(count = 100) then
                                    next_state <= p2;
                                end if;
                          else
                              P_out <= '0';
                          end if;
                    when P2 =>
                       if(modes = "001") then
                                 if (count < 140) then
                                        P_out <= '1';
                                        count <= count+1;
                                        next_state <= p2;
                                  elsif(count < 400) then
                                        P_out <= '0';
                                        count <= count+1;
                                        next_state <= p2;
                                  elsif(count = 400) then
                                       next_state <= P3;
                                  end if;
                        elsif (modes = "010") then    
                                if (count < 140) then
                                    P_out <= '1';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p2;
                                 elsif(count < 1050) then
                                    P_out <= '0';
                                    count <= count+1;
                                    next_state <= p2;
                                elsif(count = 1050) then
                                    next_state <= P3;
                                end if;
                        else
                             P_out <= '0';
                        end if;
                    when P3 =>
                        if(modes = "001") then
                                 if (count < 440) then 
                                      count <= count +1;
                                      P_out <= '1';
                                      next_state <= p3;
                                 elsif (temp = 50000) then
                                      count <= 0;
                                      --temp <= 1;
                                      next_state <= P1;
                                 else
                                      P_out <= '0';
                                      next_state <= P3;
                                 end if;
                         elsif(Modes = "010") then
                                if (count < 1090) then 
                                      count <= count +1;
                                      P_out <= '1';
                                      next_state <= P3;
                                 elsif (temp = 50000) then
                                      count <= 0;
                                      --temp <= 1;
                                      next_state <= P1;
                                 else
                                      P_out <= '0';
                                      next_state <= P3;
                                 end if;
                         else
                             P_out <= '0';
                         end if;
             end case;
            end if;
    end Process;                
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm not getting desired output. after adding temp to the sensitivity list of second process i also start getting pulses but desired signal is still far away

Comment: I forgot to mention that I haven't checked the functionality though, Could you show us the wave you are getting now? for more clarity

Comment: Hi I have added as an answer please have a look